# Service to upload images and videos to (S3, CloudFront etc)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, cloud-storage

I am looking for a service to upload videos and images from my mobile applications (frontend). I have heard about Amazon S3 and CloudFront. I am looking for a service that will store them, and will also be able to check if they meet certain criteria (for example, maximum file size of 3MB per picture), and return an error to the client if the file doesn't meet the criteria. Does Amazon S3 or CloudFront provide this? If not, is there any other recommended service for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the AWS SDK. Here follows an example of the Java version (Amazon provides SDKs for different languages):

```
/**
 * It stores the given file name in S3 and returns the key under which the file has been stored
 * @param resource
 * @param bucketName
 * @return
 */
public String storeProfileImage(File resource, String bucketName, String username) {

    String resourceUrl = null;

    if (!resource.exists()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file " + resource.getAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");

    }

    long lengthInBytes = resource.length();

    //For demo purposes. You should use a configurable property for the max size
    if (lengthInBytes > (3 * 1024)) {
        //Your error handling here
    }

    AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read);

    String key = username + "/profilePicture." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(resource.getName());

    try {
        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, resource).withAccessControlList(acl));
        resourceUrl = s3Client.getResourceUrl(bucketName, key);
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        LOG.error("A client exception occurred while trying to store the profile" +
                " image {} on S3. The profile image won't be stored", resource.getAbsolutePath(), ace);
    }

    return resourceUrl;

}
```

You can also perform other operations, e.g. check if the bucket exists before storing the image

```
/**
 * Returns the root URL where the bucket name is located.
 * <p>Please note that the URL does not contain the bucket name</p>
 * @param bucketName The bucket name
 * @return the root URL where the bucket name is located.
 */
public String ensureBucketExists(String bucketName) {

    String bucketUrl = null;

    try {
        if (!s3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)) {
            LOG.warn("Bucket {} doesn't exists...Creating one");
            s3Client.createBucket(bucketName);
            LOG.info("Created bucket: {}", bucketName);
        }
        bucketUrl = s3Client.getResourceUrl(bucketName, null) + bucketName;
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        LOG.error("An error occurred while connecting to S3. Will not execute action" +
                " for bucket: {}", bucketName, ace);
    }


    return bucketUrl;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm a fan of Amazon Web Services :-) Oh, BTW, you were asking about CloudFront. CloudFront is a Content Distribution Network (CDN). So as long as you place your files to an S3 bucket and then create a CF distribution that uses that bucket, the content will be served to your users from the nearest location to them.